# Convenience initializer with non-optional property

Tags: swift, initialization, option-type

An object of mine has an integer ID. Since this is a required property I am not defining it as an optional and I am requiring it in the designated initializer:

```
class Thing {

    var uniqueID: Int
    var name: String?

    init (uniqueID: Int) {
        self.uniqueID = uniqueID
    }       

}
```

Since I am creating one of these from some JSON, the usage is along the lines of:

```
if let uniqueID = dictionary["id"] as? Int {
    let thing = Thing(uniqueID: unique)
}
```

Next, I would like to be able to add a convenience initializer to the Thing class that accepts the dictionary object and sets the properties accordingly. This includes the required `uniqueID` and some other optional properties. My best effort so far is:

```
convenience init (dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    if let uniqueID = dictionary["id"] as? Int {
        self.init(uniqueID: uniqueID)
        //set other values here?
    }
        //or here?
}
```

But of course this isn't sufficient since the designated initializer isn't called on all paths of the conditional.

How should I be handling this scenario? Is it even possible? Or should I accept that `uniqueID` must be an optional?

Answer (score 5):

You have a couple of options with this one. One is a [failable initialisers](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17):

```
convenience init?(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    if let uniqueID = dictionary["id"] as? Int {
        self.init(uniqueID: uniqueID)
    } else {
        self.init(uniqueID: -1)
        return nil
    }
}
```

Technically this can be tweaked a bit (mainly depending on your preference/version of swift), but my person preference is something as follows:

```
class func fromDictionary(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) -> Thing? {
    if let uniqueID = dictionary["id"] as? Int {
        return self.init(uniqueID: uniqueID)
    }

    return nil
}
```

All together, as a playground:

```
class Thing {
    var uniqueID: Int
    var name: String?

    init(uniqueID: Int) {
        self.uniqueID = uniqueID
    }

    convenience init?(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        if let uniqueID = dictionary["id"] as? Int {
            self.init(uniqueID: uniqueID)
        } else {
            self.init(uniqueID: -1)
            return nil
        }
    }

    class func fromDictionary(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) -> Thing? {
        if let uniqueID = dictionary["id"] as? Int {
            return self.init(uniqueID: uniqueID)
        }

        return nil
    }
}

let firstThing = Thing(uniqueID: 1)
let secondThing = Thing(dictionary: ["id": 2])
let thirdThing = Thing(dictionary: ["not_id": 3])
let forthThing = Thing.fromDictionary(["id": 4])
let fithThing = Thing.fromDictionary(["not_id": 4])
```

Comment: I see - so the dictionary builder is no longer an initializer. I had;t considered that. Dammit now I have to re-figure out why convenience initializers are even used at all. Back to the docs.

Comment: @BenPackard Convenience initialisers are useful in a few cases, but I usually only use them when it's not failable since swift's failable initialisers are a bit of a pain due to having to give a value to every stored property.

Comment: @nhgrif In this case I am suggesting the removal of the dictionary-accepting initialiser and instead opting for a class function to perform a similar job, leaving the only init method being the one that accepts all arguments and can not fail, as you suggest?

Comment: @JosephDuffy I removed my comment.  I think I misread something.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is probably to use a failable initializer, which will either return an instantiated object or `nil`.

Because Swift objects cannot be partially constructed and convenience initializers must call a non-convenience initializer, we must still do something in the failure case.

The result will look something like this:

```
convenience init?(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    if let uniqueID = dictionary["id"] as? Int {
        self.init(uniqueID: uniqueID)
    } else {
        self.init(uniqueID: 0)
        return nil
    }
}
```

---

Generally speaking, our non-convenience initializer(s) should be one that accepts all arguments, and convenience initializers should be methods which don't require some of the arguments.

For example, I might make my default initializer look like this:

```
init(uniqueID: Int, name: String? = nil) {
    self.uniqueID = uniqueID
    self.name = name
}
```

This allows us to call the constructor in several different ways:

```
let thing1 = Thing(1)
let thing2 = Thing(2, nil)
let thing3 = Thing(3, "foo")
let thing4 = Thing(4, myUnwrappedStringVar)
let thing5 = Thing(5, myWrappedStringOptional)
```

And that already covers a lot of use cases for us.

So, let's add another convenience initializer that accepts an optional `Int`.

```
convenience init?(uniqueID: Int? = nil, name: String? = nil) {
    if let id = uniqueID {
        self.init(uniqueID: id, name: name)
    } else {
        self.init(uniqueID: 0)
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now we can take an `Int?` for our `uniqueID` argument and just fail when it's `nil`.

So, one more to accept the dictionary.

```
convenience init?(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    let uniqueID = dictionary["id"] as? Int
    let name = dictionary["name"] as? String
    self.init(uniqueID: uniqueID, name: name)
}
```

We still have the slightly weird initialize then return `nil` pattern in our first convenience constructor, but everything else we build on top of this can simply call *that* convenience initializer and doesn't require the weird pattern.

In the initializer that takes the dictionary, if there's no `id` key, or if it's something that's not an `Int`, then the `let uniqueID` will be `nil`, so when we call the other constructor, it will call the one that accepts an `Int?`, be passed `nil`, return `nil`, and therefore the one we called will return `nil`.

Comment: I see, thanks. Would you consider this an unusual setup? I ask because this is some of the first Swift I have written so I would like to use 'standard' patterns wherever possible (and where they exist). How would you handle this if it were your code? Just let the ID be optional?

Comment: I don't think this is too particularly odd necessarily.  What I would do entirely depends on a lot more context.  If you're *really* interested in figuring out the best way to do this, you can always post a question on [codereview.se] with a working version of your code.

Comment: @BenPackard I've expanded my answer.  Perhaps it'll help you out.  Implement these methods as such and set a breakpoint to trace the execution path through this code when you initialize with a dictionary.

Comment: What's the benefit of (generally) creating an init that accepts even optional properties vs simply setting them from the caller once they are created? Anything other than style/convention? And would you use the same approach if your object had 10 properties? 20?

Comment: Some objects don't make sense until all of their instance variables have values.  Consider an object that's supposed to represent a rectange.  In order for any instance of this object to make sense, we **must** have a height and a width.  As for objects with lots of properties?  Other than something UI-related that's going to have a lot of UI elements as properties, I've never found the need to create a class with so many properties that were all necessary at initialization time.

Comment: Given the simplicity of your `Thing` class, it's very easy to take in the `name` parameter (optionally) without really overcomplicating things.  And it's nice to allow the user to do this in the initializer.  With 20 properties, it might be a different story... but you might need some more abstraction if you've got an object with 20 properties.  I'd have to see a concrete example though.